# How to align control in headerToolbar SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I've multiple control in one headerToolbar. I want to align one of them (Seach Field) at the right most. both images are from two different screen size. I use  because when i decrease the screen size seachfield should not hide and come at next line.
[image: Small Screen]  [image: Large Scren]
I want to keep seach field at right most. 
the code for this is

```
<headerToolbar>
<Toolbar id="dsdfgfanfgjd">
    <content>
        <HBox width='100%' wrap='Wrap'>
            <items>
                <FormattedText class="customPanelHeader"
                    htmlText=""/>
                <ToolbarSpacer>
                    <layoutData>
                        <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" minWidth="22px"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </ToolbarSpacer>
                <SearchField id="searchFilter"  placeholder="filter value" value="{/searchFilter}" width="12em"
                    liveChange=".onChangedSearchFilter" valueLiveUpdate="true"/>
            </items>
        </HBox>
    </content>
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the SearchBox at the right end irrespective of the screen size, use below code:

```
<Toolbar height='auto'>
                <content>
                    <HBox width='100%' wrap='Wrap'>
                        <items>
                            <Text text='text0' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text1' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text2' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text3' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text4' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text5' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text6' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text7' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text8' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text9' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text10' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text11' width='3rem' />
                            <Text text='text12' width='3rem' />
                            <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
                            <HBox justifyContent='End'>
                                <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData
                                    growFactor='1'>
                                </FlexItemData>
                                </layoutData>
                                <Input id="searchFilter" class="searchFilterInput"
                                placeholder="filter value" value="{/searchFilter}" width="100%"
                                liveChange=".onChangedSearchFilter" valueLiveUpdate="true" />
                            <core:Icon class="searchFilterIcon" size="1.75rem"
                                src="sap-icon://search" tooltip="search" />
                            </HBox>
                        </items>
                    </HBox>
                </content>
            </Toolbar>
```